# Does Hadoop namenode use long lived socket connections?

Tags: hadoop

When use hadoop, `set dfs.namenode.handler.count = 8000,`

1. Is this setting OK?
2. Will namenode create 8000 thread to privode service for client? if yes, assume each thread costs 2M memory, it will cost namnode 16G memory?

Comment: why you need so many handlers? and yes, NN creates 1 threads per handler.

Comment: when handler number is small, calling hadoop fs shell's get can not get hdfs file, I donot know why.So I have to increase the handlers.

Comment: I write a program which needs to get many files from hdfs, when namonode memory usage > 75%, it will find that many files can not be got from hdfs

Comment: looks like misuse of hdfs for me. you should consider another architecture or filesystem (hbase? elliptics? rsync+nginx?), hdfs is _not_ designed for such usage. http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2009/02/the-small-files-problem/

Answer (score 0):

1> Yes

2> Yeah it will create 8000 thread which will cost u 16G memory. Doing so will increase memory utilization of the namenode but this may result in reduced perfomance due to I/O contention for the metadata updates.

Comment: Ok, when dfsclient connets the namenode , does it use long lived socket connections?